# Authenticating with ClientLogin and using the Google Reader API in Android

Tags: authentication, request, google-reader

I have to **post a message from my android application to Google Reader**. I'm Authenticating with ClientLogin and using the Google Reader API.When I'm trying to send the authentication request it's giving an error.

**HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**

I think the client was able to communicate with the server but the server could not find what was requested.I'm giving the following url 
 postURL = "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit" as 
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);.

Please tell me the solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ClientLogin you will probably need only 2 kinds of tokens to do what you need with the unnoficial Google Reader API:

- Authentication Token - This is the main authentication token, and you'll need to send this in the header of every GET/POST request to the API, otherwise you'll get an error (not the one you're having, though). You can do a POST to this url for this (I have a full code example ahead): https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin
- Edit Token - This is the edit token, and you'll need to send this as a form parameter of POST request to any edit APIs (like the http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit you've mentioned). You can do a GET to this url for this (I have a code example ahead): http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token

---

**Getting to the 404 error you're reporting**, it must be that you have a typo in your url. Copy my url and try it out. Double check it, side by side. Here is the Java code I've used for this - you can try it out also:

```
    private static final String _AUTHPARAMS = "GoogleLogin auth=";
    private static final String _GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
    private static final String _READER_BASE_URL = "http://www.google.com/reader/";
    private static final String _API_URL = _READER_BASE_URL + "api/0/";
    private static final String _TOKEN_URL = _API_URL + "token";
    private static final String _USER_INFO_URL = _API_URL + "user-info";
    private static final String _USER_LABEL = "user/-/label/";
    private static final String _TAG_LIST_URL = _API_URL + "tag/list";
    private static final String _EDIT_TAG_URL = _API_URL + "tag/edit";
    private static final String _RENAME_TAG_URL = _API_URL + "rename-tag";
    private static final String _DISABLE_TAG_URL = _API_URL + "disable-tag";
    private static final String _SUBSCRIPTION_URL = _API_URL
    + "subscription/edit";
    private static final String _SUBSCRIPTION_LIST_URL = _API_URL
    + "subscription/list";

    public static String getGoogleAuthKey() throws IOException {

        String _USERNAME = "USER_EMAIL@gmail.com";
        String _PASSWORD = "USER_PASSWORD";

        Document doc = Jsoup
        .connect(_GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL)
        .data("accountType", "GOOGLE", "Email", _USERNAME, "Passwd",
                _PASSWORD, "service", "reader", "source",
                "[YOUR_APP_ID_GOES_HERE].apps.googleusercontent.com")
        .userAgent("[YOUR_APP_ID_GOES_HERE].apps.googleusercontent.com")
        .timeout(4000).post();

// RETRIEVES THE RESPONSE TEXT inc SID and AUTH. We only want the AUTH
// key.
String _AUTHKEY = doc
        .body()
        .text()
        .substring(doc.body().text().indexOf("Auth="),
                doc.body().text().length());
_AUTHKEY = _AUTHKEY.replace("Auth=", "");
return _AUTHKEY;
```

}

You can see a code example for getting the edit token and doing an edit in my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434146/how-to-mark-items-read-with-google-reader-api).

See my answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752076/where-to-start-with-google-reader-as-an-api) if you want documentation (unofficial but well structured) - there is no official doc...

The code is based on http://www.chrisdadswell.co.uk/android-coding-example-authenticating-clientlogin-google-reader-api/